# How to test Alexa Flash Skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-flash-briefing-skill

I have created one "Flash Briefing skill" and I wanted to test it.

Is is possible to test "Flash Briefing skill" without the echo device??

or if it is possible then please let me know how??

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

@Joomler
Two ways:

1. Use echosim : `https://echosim.io/`
2. Use the tester in the amazon developer site.

Comment: these two I already know. it will be great if you can tell me how i can integrate **echosim** with my "Flash Briefing skill".

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling to test my Alexa briefing skill. I found this post - https://www.voice2biz.com/alexa-flash-briefing-woes/

I says you can't use the Alexa Test tab to test a Flash Briefing skill.